# I got a query error when calling the user login in django

Tags: django, django-models

views.py

```
from .models import Profile
@login_required(login_url='/signin')
def settings(request):
    user_profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'setting.html',{'user_profile':user_profile})
```

I think the error is in :`user_profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)`
but I don't know why

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
class Profile(models.Model):
    user         = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_user      = models.IntegerField()
    bio          = models.TextField(blank=True)
    profileimg   = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics/', default='default-profile.png')
    location     = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    birth_date   = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

ERROR

[image]

Comment: there is no profile for this user. First you need to change ForeginKey to OneToOneField. what for is user_id field? then surrund the query with try/except statment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a `User` instance for the user you are trying to log in as, however that does not mean there is a `Profile` present as well. You need to make sure every `User` has a profile. There are a few ways to do it:

1. (Recommended) Override the `save()` method on `User` to automatically create a `Profile` when a new user is created. e.g:

```py
class User(..):
    # user properties

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            Profile.objects.create(user=user)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

2. Handle the action on the API call. So in your function you can check if the user has a profile, if they don't you may wish to create one. For example:

```py
def settings(request):
    user_profile=Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    return render(request,'setting.html',{'user_profile':user_profile})
```

Here I used `get_or_create`, but you are free to use `try/except` blocks or whatever suits your backend logic best!

Comment: thanks for the answer but method 1 and 2 didn't work, but for your suggestion in method 2 I have implemented it with a different code, apparently the error is in the admin account that is not registered in the profile